# part.getFilename() returning null for split filename

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a mime message which includes the following part:

```
------=_Part_1913_425829774.1624970691824
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename*0=AS_YOU_CAN_SEE_HERE_A_REALLY_LONG_FILENAME_WAS_USED_FOR_THE_IMAGE;
    filename*1=WHICH_CAUSES_IT_TO_BE_SPLIT.jpg
```

The filename has been split into two parts and with javax.mail 1.6.1 and 1.6.2 the call to part.getFileName() returns null.

Is there a work around for this other than parsing the content disposition manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set "mail.strictly\_mime.parm\_folding" in javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628139/set-mail-strictly-mime-parm-folding-in-javamail)

Comment: Basically, the splitting is correct (as per RFC 2231), but the email client (or library) is not handling it.  There is a way to tell jakarta-mail to not do RFC 2231 compliant splitting of overly long parameters.  The downside is that the mail transport is not obliged to correctly handle lines > 80 characters, so the overly long filename could (in theory) be truncated in transit.

Comment: For now I'm manually I'm stitching the file name parts together so I guess I'll go with that.  I assume the expected behavior is for part.getFileName() to return the full file name regardless of whether it was split or not.

Comment: So ... I am confused.  Are you complaining that your client is **sending** emails with split filenames?  Or is the problem that your client is not correctly dealing with emails that it has **received** with split emails?

Comment: If this is a problem with correctly *handling* the split parameters, see [How to decode an attachment chunked filename in javamail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921896) ... which explains how to tell javax.mail to reassemble them.

Comment: The issue is when my code is processing a message that it's reading from a file. When that code tries to get the image filename nothing is retuned.

Comment: So does the above link about "chunked filenames" solve your problem?  Did you try doing what it says?